# MATLAB: websave function doesn't save the image

Tags: matlab

I am using the following function to save map from [mapquest](https://www.mapquest.com) as a png file as follows

```
f_name='abc.png';
url='https://www.mapquest.com?center=1.34,103.683'

%other parameters also go through the url.

websave(f_name, url);
```

Image is saved but it cannot be displayed throwing the following error.

```
Error using imread>get_format_info (line 543)
Unable to determine the file format.
Error in imread (line 391)
        fmt_s = get_format_info(fullname);
```

Subsequently following line also throws an error.

```
[M, Mcolor] = imread(filepath);
```

When image is opened a message is displayed

> File format is not supported.

But if its extension is changed for example to `html` it does try to load the actual web page display.

Any clues will be highly appreciated

Comment: The URL you are pointing to is not that of an image, but of a web page.  Matlab is not a browser so cannot render this in any way.  websave is designed to work with web resources which are already images.

Comment: e.g. `websave('test.png','https://www.sample-videos.com/img/Sample-png-image-100kb.png');` will save a test image you can then open.

Comment: I need to import this web page as a background of my plot how can I achieve this any solution? @EuanSmith

Comment: You can't, not with Matlab. It is not the right tools for the job. If you still think you need to then you are looking at automated browser control, using tools like webdriver to control chrome, or phantonjs to render in a node server. You really need to ask yourself if you really do need this, because this is not simple.

Comment: Thanks @EuanSmith your above answer did the right job for me. Appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to find the way to do this after a little research!

Static APIs are used in this regard and are available with maps like **Google, Mapquest etc.**

These static APIs convert the web page of map to its respective image, to put an example for **Mapquest** it can be used using [this](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/static-map-api/v5/map/)